# Get data from content provider in React Native

Tags: react-native

Could suggest any solution or code sample to get data from content provider android in React Native.
Currently, I use 'react-native-fs' but it can not get data from content provider, or i maybe mistake with this library.
My code

```
const uriContent = 'content://xxx.provider/info_all'
const existFile = await RNFS.exists(uriContent)
    if (existFile) {
        const fileContent = await RNFS.readFile(uriContent, 'utf8')
        try {
            const newData = JSON.parse(fileContent)
            // console.log('GOT RESULT UUID', newData.uuid);
            if (newData !== undefined && newData !== null &&
                newData.uuid !== undefined && newData.uuid !== null && newData.uuid.length > 0) {
                return newData.uuid
            } else {
                return ''
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message, error.code)
            return ''
        }
    } else {
        return ''
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
    RNFS.stat(uriContent) 
instead of 
    RNFS.exists(uriContent).

State method will provide file state in promise like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs#statfilepath-string-promisestatresult

Comment: You can use RNFS.stat(uriContent) instead of RNFS.exists(uriContent).
===> I used that for check the path content:// exist or not.
i concern about how to get data from content provider in android
Thank you for you answer.